# Broadleaf Commerce 3.0 Missing Artifacts

Tags: java, spring, maven, broadleaf-commerce

I am following steps listed for Broadleaf 3.0 from the [link](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/current/Getting-Started.html).

Using the Eclipse-workspace with M2E plugin, I tried Maven Update Project and refresh. 
However, the maven multi-module projects have unresolved build errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1 pom.xml /core   line 3  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.3.1    pom.xml /admin  line 3  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.3.1    pom.xml /core   line 3  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1 pom.xml /site   line 3  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.3.1    pom.xml /site   line 3  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1 pom.xml /admin  line 3  Maven Dependency Problem
```

I am using STS v3.2.0( I even tried with Eclipse Kepler version, same issue).
No build problems were present when using previous Broadleaf version 2.2.

I also searched maven repository for missing jars: [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.floggy.3rd.org.eclipse.core/jobs/3.3.1.R33x_v20070709) and [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.floggy.3rd.org.eclipse.equinox/registry/3.3.1.R33x_v20070802) but errors are unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I employed a dirty and hacky workaround to fix Maven Build issues.

I had to manually download the closest version missing jars from maven repository, change versioning of jars in maven install command. For example:

The only available version for jar `org.eclipse.equinox.common` is v3.6.0.v20100503 present [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.equinox/org.eclipse.equinox.common/3.6.0.v20100503):

Then install artifact with required version(v3.3.0) using maven command in following way:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=~/Downloads/org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.6.0.v20100503.jar -DgroupId=org.eclipse.equinox -DartifactId=common -Dversion=3.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**Please note you will have to download/install 5-6 jars in this manner**.

I got the demo site and admin to work so far with no errors. Thus, the jar version mismatch hasn't impacted the Broadleaf Demo, atleast for now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this still an issue for you? I see all three of those depdencies as available on Maven central as seen here:

- [registry](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.equinox%7Cregistry%7C3.3.0-v20070522%7Cjar)
- [common](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.equinox%7Ccommon%7C3.3.0-v20070426%7Cjar)
- [jobs](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.core%7Cjobs%7C3.3.0-v20070423%7Cjar)

If you make sure that you're not using a mirror of Maven central that doesn't have those JARs available, it should pull down if you run `mvn install -U`

Comment: The solution I posted previously worked for me..thanks for the post.